# Why won't Excel Filter function work with Month(A1)=Month(G1)?

Tags: excel, filter

I have a rather detailed Review\Score Card workbook where I tally scores when checking the previous day's work before submitting it for billing.  On the Scorecard worksheet I want to show a list of review comments for the jobs from the previous month (monthly review).  A simple filter with the tech's name works fine, but when I include month filtering it does not work.

**Working**

```
=FILTER('Install Reviews'!A:AD, ('Install Reviews'!B:B=ScoreCard!L3))
```

**Not Working** - Returns CALC error.

```
=FILTER('Install Reviews'!A:AD, ('Install Reviews'!B:B=ScoreCard!L3)*(MONTH('Install Reviews'!E:E)=MONTH(ScoreCard!B6)))
```

The 'Install Reviews'!E:E column contains valid dates.  A simple formula in a separate cell of =MONTH('Install Reviews'!E120) returns "12".  The value in ScoreCard!B6 is also a valid date and MONTH(ScoreCard!B6) returns "12", so I know the values in the referenced cells are valid dates.

Doing more testing I can return the month I want with Greater Than OR Less Than statements, but why won't the MONTH()=MONTH() statement work?

**Working**

```
FILTER('Install Reviews'!A:AD,('Install Reviews'!B:B=ScoreCard!B4)*(('Install Reviews'!E:E>B6)*('Install Reviews'!E:E<EOMONTH(B6,0))))
```

Comment: What does Formulas > Evaluate Formula show if you step through?

Comment: What do you mean by "`does not work`"?  I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided.

Comment: Your second formula seems correct.  I only got a #CALC error when there were no matches.  I would suggest entering something into if_empty parameter of your filter.  If it's not finding matches then double check that you have data that matches for column B and column E.